# Intel bga 1170 pinout

Tags: embedded, bga, intel, soc

I have been researching this question:
What is the pinout for an intel celeron N2930 soc?

But I cannot find it in the datasheet, or on google.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/products/bay-trail/pentium-n3520-j2850-celeron-n2920-n2820-n2815-n2806-j1850-j1750-datasheet.html)

Pages 23-42 describe the physical layout. Page 108 is the package diagram.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

For the Intel Atom E3800 series, it uses the same pin mapping, so it should work.

Comment: If this is the answer to your own question. Please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Assume you refer to e3800 product family data sheet.